# SQLite How to find the most common occurrences of a value

Tags: sql, sqlite

Say I have a table A with attributes X
How do I find the X's with the largest occurrences? (There can be multiple that have the same highest occurrence)

i.e.
table A

```
 X
--
'a'
'b'
'c'
'c'
'b'
```

I would want to get back

```
X
--
'b'
'c'
```

I can't use the keyword ALL in Sqlite so I'm at a loss.

I thought of getting the counts of each X and then sorting it and then somehow using ORDER BY DESC so that the biggest is at the top and then LIMIT with a comparison to check if values below the first tuple are equal (which means they are just as common) but I'm not sure about LIMIT syntax and if I can have a condition like that

Please give a hint and not the answer, are there any resources I can reference so I can figure out a way?

Comment: In oracle I would have used count() along with Partition_by()

Comment: @Arnab SQLite is sadly short on view functions.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This takes care of multiple values having maximum occurence

```
SELECT X FROM yourTable
GROUP BY X
HAVING COUNT(*) = (
                   SELECT MAX(Cnt) 
                   FROM(
                         SELECT COUNT(*) as Cnt
                         FROM yourTable
                         GROUP BY X
                        ) tmp
                    )
```

[**SQL FIDDLE**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!5/5d642/7)

Comment: How can i get counted value from it i.e that 2?

Answer (score 10):

Query like

```
SELECT x,COUNT(x) AS cnt FROM a
GROUP BY x
ORDER BY cnt DESC;
```

and stop processing the result rows when `cnt` changes.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use a `LIMIT` clause if you don't know apriori how many entries might share the same count.

Just request the data as described in your question, but do it a row at a time and stop when the returned count differs from that from the previous row.

Answer (score -1):

```
select X, count(X) from table group by X;
```

Comment: That would give me the count of every X, right, but not the most common ones