# ORMLite search for rows with most common column

Tags: android, sqlite, ormlite

I'm using ORMLite for working with local database and have an issue with one custom query.

I need to get one row which's some column's value is most common in table.

E.g. I have a column `text` and I have 3 rows with value `text0`, 4 rows with value `text1` and 5 rows with value `text2`. I need to get one of the rows which have value `text2` of `text` column.

Can I do this with ORMLite's query builder or I should run a raw query?

This is raw sql query which works fine and returns array of strings.

```
        Dao<Case, Long> caseDao = getHelper().getCaseDao();
        GenericRawResults<String[]> cases = caseDao.queryRaw("SELECT * ," +
                " COUNT('name') AS 'name_occurrence'" +
                " FROM 'MEDICAL_CASE'" +
                " GROUP BY 'name'" +
                " ORDER BY 'name_occurrence' DESC" +
                " LIMIT 1", new String[]{});
```

After getting strings I have to create an instance of my model, set values and do my jon with that object.

But it's a bit ugly that's why I'm asking if it's possible with methods of ormlite.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Can I do this with ORMLite's query builder or I should run a raw query?

Any results that aren't an entity need to be done through ORMLite's `dao.queryRaw(...)` methods.  If you can do it with SQL then you can do it through those methods.

See: http://ormlite.com/docs/raw-queries

You can't use the standard entity mapper because you are doing a `SELECT *, COUNT('name')`.  ORMLite wouldn't know what to do with the `COUNT(...)` field.

Comment: My result should be an entity. I need a row (sql row / instance of my model class). I just was wondering how to get the most common item in table with ormlite's methods.

Comment: How would you do it in SQL?

Comment: here is a question which represents my case and it's solution:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21377319/sqlite-how-to-find-the-most-common-occurrences-of-a-value

Comment: The problem with your query is the extra select `COUNT` column.  ORMLite won't know what to do with that.  You could doing the entity map yourself using your own mapping function.